# Is it possible to have multiple document types for one NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?

Tags: cocoa, macos, spotlight

I have 2 different entities in my core data model: project and issue. Each type has unique attributes, so I want to use different UTI document type for each entity. Each UTI document type should have an extension. Unfortunately, NSPersistentStoreCoordinator allows to set only one file extension.

So my question how to export more than one document type with the same extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this in target->Get Info->Properties:
[image]

I haven't tested, but I assume something like this would work.

Comment: can you have more that one document subclass? because that will work.

Comment: I'm using Core Data, not NSDocument.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible (Mac OS X 10.6).